# Compute Node computes data from previous flow

Tags: ibm-integration-bus

This is how my flow looks like:

`File Input -> File Read -> Compute -> Mapping -> Compute -> File Output`

From file read node I save data to `${LocalEnvironment}`. Also tried `${Environment}`. And this is what happens behind Compute Node:

1. Send file A - data inside environment of A is computed (edit after answer -> is not computed, flow stops unexpectedly).
2. Send file B - data inside environment of A is computed.
3. Send file C - data inside environment of B is computed.
4. Send file D - data inside environment of C is computed.

How this offset is even possible? `${LocalEnvironment}` should be reset at the beggining of the flow.

**EDIT**:

Never use Environment variable. Local variables should be stored inside `$LocalEnvironment/Variables`.

[Explanation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSMKHH_9.0.0/com.ibm.scenarios.doc/gop_03/topics/bj60052_.htm)

Got that. And even now I think my Variables aren't being cleared. File Read still produces `$LocalEnvironment/Variables/BLOB/BLOB` from previous run.

**EDIT2:***
Node settings:
File Input:

```
Input directory: C:\Users\User1\Documents\In
File pattern: *
Action on successful processing: move to mqsiarchive
Message domain: XMLNS (I know it should be XMLNSC but it works)
Use XMLNSC compact parser...: check
```

File read:

```
Input directory: C:\Users\User1\Documents\In\mqsiarchive
File name or pattern: *
Action: Delete
Request directory property location: $LocalEnvironment/Destination/File/Directory
Request filename property location: $LocalEnvironment/Destination/File/Name
Offset property location: $LocalEnvironment/Destination/File/Offset
Length property location: $LocalEnvironment/Destination/File/Length
Result data location: $ResultRoot
Output data location: $OutputLocalEnvironment/Variables
Copy local environment: check
Record selection expression: true()
```

Compute nodes:

```
Compute mode: LocalEnvironment and Message
```

File output (this one doesn't matter much since problem occurs even without it):

```
Output directory: C:\Users\User1\Documents\Out
Filename or pattern: test.txt
Stage in mqsitransit...: check
Data location: $Body
Request directory property location: $LocalEnvironment/Destination/File/Directory
Request filename property location: $LocalEnvironment/Destination/File/Name
```

Properties that I didn't mention: default

Comment: The `Environment` and `LocalEnvironment` are cleared after the flow commits/rollbacks its work. Can you share the directory/file properties of the File Input, File Read and File Output nodes?

Comment: Sure! I edited main question. Some properties in LocalEnvironment are being cleared like wildcard and some not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it works like this:

- In the 1. transaction the File Read node has nothing to read because archive directory is empty. Therefore the message A from File Input is processed.
- In the 2. transaction the File Read nodes finds message A from 1. transaction. Therefore message B just gets archived and message A from File Read node gets processed (again).

Comment: I just checked my mqsiarchive and this is exactly what happens! File A gets into mqsiarchive but mqsiarchive is empty so flow stops and after stop file appears in mqsiarchive. Then I place file B, A gets processed and when it's done file B shows up in mqsiarchive and this is how offset occurs. I need to design better flow. Thank you once again, I have to admit that I'm impressed :)!